# Access member function of another .cpp within same source file?

Tags: c++, class

I am working in Visual C++. I have two .cpp files in the same source file. How can I access another class (.cpp) function in this main .cpp?

Comment: Could you please explain why you don't want to use an header file? That might be useful to help you with your problem.

Comment: I don't think he's said he doesn't want to.  It looks like he doesn't know *how* to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should define your class in a .h file, and implement it in a .cpp file. Then, include your .h file wherever you want to use your class.

For example

file use_me.h

```
#include <iostream>
class Use_me{

   public: void echo(char c);

};
```

file use_me.cpp

```
#include "use_me.h" //use_me.h must be placed in the same directory as use_me.cpp

void Use_me::echo(char c){std::cout<<c<<std::endl;}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "use_me.h"//use_me.h must be in the same directory as main.cpp
    int main(){
       char c = 1;

       Use_me use;
       use.echo(c);

       return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Sure you can. Copy the `Use_me` class declaration and paste it in place of the `#include` directives in *main.cpp* and *use_me.cpp*. That's essentially what `#include` does anyway. You would be stupid for doing that, but it's certainly possible to do.

Comment: `use_me.h` is not necessary being in the same directory as `main.cpp` since you can include it like `#include <some_path/use_me.h>`

Answer (score 4):

Without creating header files. Use `extern` modifier.

a.cpp

```
extern int sum (int a, int b);

int main()
{
    int z = sum (2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

b.cpp

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure functions have extern linkage by default anyway. You only need `extern` on variables.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the function declarations in an .hpp flie, and then `#include` it in the main.cpp file.

For instance, if the function you're calling is:

```
int foo(int bar)
{
   return bar/2;
}
```

you need to create a foobar.hpp file with this:

```
int foo(int bar);
```

and add the following to all .cpp files that call `foo`:

```
#include "foobar.hpp"
```

Comment: simply said,
another.cpp
class A
{
-----
}
and in main.cpp ,here is there's is any possibilities  to create an object to class A in main.cpp?